# '=': cannot convert from 'int (*)[5]' to 'int *'

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, visual-c++, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x[] = { 1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 };
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &x;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler tells me that '=': cannot convert from 'int (*)[5]' to 'int *'. What does this mean? The part I do not understand is that `ptr` being a pointer can always store the address of x that itself is a pointer that points to the base element of the array.

Comment: You should instead do `ptr = x;` to assign one pointer to another

Comment: If `x` was not a pointer (it's array, so it is pointer to first element in the array), but only one `int`, then your code would be valid. What CoryKramer says is true.

Comment: @Rorschach:  `x` is ***not*** a pointer.  It is an array of 5 ints.  When used in an expression, it will decay to a pointer to its first element, but that doesn't mean it *is* a pointer (and the difference can be very important when considering multiple levels).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An array name is a constant pointer to the first element of the array. So your variable `x` is a pointer to `&x[0]` or x is a pointer to the address of the first element in the integer array `x`.

A pointer is a variable that stores an address. Since the array name is a pointer, it stores an address. In this case `x` is storing the address of the first element, that is, the address of `x[0]`.

You are declaring variable `ptr` as a pointer to an integer type variable. So `ptr` will also store an address when initialized.

Therefore your assignment statement `ptr = &x;` is trying to find the 'address' of an address that is already specified there when you previously stored the address of `x[0]` in `x`.

As the compiler is unable to find the 'address' of the 'address of x[0]' it produces an error.

The correct way to tell the compiler that you want to store the address of `x[0]` in the variable `ptr` is by simple telling it the following `ptr = x;` or, in other words, `ptr` is equal to the address stored in `x`, and the address stored in `x` is actually the address of `x[0]`.

Remember that both `ptr` and `x` can store addresses. Hope this helps to clarify.

Answer (score 4):

The type of the variable x is `int[5]`. The & operator applied to this variable is a pointer to an object of the type `int[5]`.

You can imagine valid declarations the following way

```
typedef int T[5];

T x = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
T *ptr = &x;
```

On the other hand you can write

```
typedef int U;

U x[5] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
U *ptr = x;
```

As you can see T and U are different types and correspondingly `T *` and `U *` are also different types. And objects of these types are initialized differently.
The type `T *` corresponds to the type `int ( * )[5]` while the type U corresponds to the type `int *`

There is no implicit conversion from the one pointer type to another. So the compiler issues an error.